# How can @ManyToOne mapping be done with linking table?

Tags: hibernate

I have the following tables in my DB:

```
CREATE TABLE TRD_parties (
    id long NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255),
    shortname varchar(16),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE TRD_funds (
    id long NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    shortname varchar(16),
    name varchar(255),
    units float,
    party_id long,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (party_id) REFERENCES TRD_parties(id)
);

CREATE TABLE TRD_funds_available4party (
    party_id long,
    fund_id long,
    FOREIGN KEY (party_id) REFERENCES TRD_parties(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (fund_id) REFERENCES TRD_funds(id)
);
```

1 Fund belongs only to single Party, and 1 Party has a list of funds. Entities look like that:

```
public class Fund{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
...

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)//no problem with this mapping
@JoinColumn(name = "partyId")
private Party party;


@Entity
@Table(name = "TRD_parties")
public class Party{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="availableFunds")//this is wrong how to map it?
private List<Fund> availableFunds;
```

My question is like in Party entity: **How can I use mapping to assign List of available funds (described in linking table TRD_funds_available4party) to a party?**

I have found some tips [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_list_mapping.htm) , but first I don't know how to adapt this example to my situation, and second would it work in Hibernate 5 with Spring Boot?

Comment: You need to specify a join table: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html. But why do you have a party_id in the funds table if you want to use a join table for this association? Or rather, why use an additional join table since you already have a party_id foreign key in the funds table?

Comment: @ JB Nizet  Actually, to practice JPA :)

Comment: @JoinTable(
            name = "TRD_funds_available4party",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "fund_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id"
            ),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "party_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id"
            )
    )
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="availableFunds")
    private List<Fund> availableFunds;

DOESN'T WORK

Comment: AnnotationException: Associations marked as mappedBy must not define database mappings like @ JoinTable or @ JoinColumn: org.kd.tradeapp.entity.Party.availableFunds

Comment: The message is pretty clear. mappedBy means: "look on the other side of the association to know how this association is mapped. i'm only the inverse side". The JoinTable annotation should be set on the other side.